# openstreetmap/postgis custom data

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, markers

I'm a newbie and I'd like to realize a project based on a local OSM with postgis +mapnik +angular and leaflet.

The project requirement is :

An ACME company owns geographically distributed equipment which has to be serviced on expiry date. They already have a postgres "ACME" database with a table "equipment" {eqID,eqcustomerID eqNameid, eqAddress, eqServiceExpiryDate}. 
ACME database (or just a table "equipment") should be integrated into 
a GIS system built on a local openstreetmap server by using postgis and mapnik and have a capability to display as markers:

1. all devices which servicing date is expired
2. all devices of a specified customer presented by different markers which depends on expire date.
3. all devices in a specified city/town

So far I got working local mapnik/postgresql server with osm data imported into the postgis database and tested with leaflet.

I know that "equipment" table should be "expanded" by long/lat values. However, I have no idea where I can put equipment data from postgres database in local osm tables and how to present them....

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of merging these two databases (also keep in mind that you might want to prevent creating a *derivative database*, see the [OSM legal FAQ](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ#3d._If_I_use_your_data_together_with_someone_else.27s_data.2C_do_I_have_to_apply_your_license_to_their_data_too.3F)) you could also just draw markers for your equipment on top of existing tiles via [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) by pulling them from your second database.

Comment: it is a inhouse project, not for publishing public.